# How to get current page's all dynamic id to make a php query for find any match in sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get all posts id from current page after 15 second interval to make server side php query. Php query will find match in Sql with id and if any data find for a particular id's, it will be .append it.

So in my current page have many div with their own dynamic post id like:

```
<div class="case" data-post-id="111">

<div class="case" data-post-id="222">

<div class="case" data-post-id="333">

<div class="case" data-post-id="anything else dynamic no">
```

And I want, my javascript will get and sent this ids to a php query for find any match in Sql.

**How to get and sent current page dynamic id** after 15 second interval.

My update script that I collect from stockoverflow and tried: (here `var CID` cannot get ids, only get first id)

```
var CID = [];  //get dynamic id 
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
   CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
    $("#newreply"+id).append("");
});
}
var tutid = '<?php echo $tutid; ?>';
function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
        tutid : tutid,
        // this way array containing all ID's can be sent:
        cid : CID
    },
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
```

server.php

```
if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['cid']){
  foreach($_REQUEST['cid'] as $key => $value){

// do query

if (!empty($data)) {
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();
    exit(0);
}
} }
```